# Is hashing on a composite-type column in PostgreSQL equivalent performance-wise to hashing multiple columns?

Tags: performance, postgresql, types, hash, indexing

I have a question about performance of hash-indexing a composite column in Postgres.
Bottom line is: is the performance identical to that of hash-indexing multiple columns, which have the same type & layout as the composite type attributes?

Let me give the specific situation:
I'm given quarter-annual database dumps that I intend to re-import in Postgres and analyze. I have no control over the format of the provided data.

It uses, in multiple places, primary keys consisting of 32-char-length hex-codes. These are, quite simply, 128-bit integers.

I simulated these primary keys in Postgres using a composite type of (bigint, bigint), and provided implicit CASTS to-and-from text.

However, I'm concerned about the performance. Is there any performance loss?

Comment: `PostgreSQL` or `Postgres` for short. [More here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Postgres).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 128 bit key makes no sense to me. How many of the key values are actually valid (at any time)? A second problem could be that the 128bit thingies are more or less random, and "consecutive" rows will hop to and fro in the keyspace (which will lead to bad clustering of records). Another aspect of this would be that given the first 64 bit of the key, the second 64 bit would *virtually* be functional dependant (and thus: *almost* redundant) The actual compare of two keyfields instead of one is not that troublesome performance-wise, IMHO), it only will cause ugly queries.
But I don't know your data...

The data-vault approach to this kind of problem would be to just create your own surrogate key (int or bigint) and use this instead of the 128 bits monster. A 1<->1 lookup table would do the rest. This is also a cure for the problem of the BigThing changing over time, say from a char(64) with only hex characters allowed, to a char(64) with mmencoded payload.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, wildplasser. What you're saying makes a lot of sense. I think I will take your advice, make my own key (bigint should work, since data volume is not that excessive), and make 1<-->1 lookup tables for any tables that use the BigThing.

Comment: Thanks. The data-vault approach to "external" (very-foreign;-) keys really is a good approach, since you have no influence on them, you should respect them (and treat them as "data"). Your importing step may get a bit more complicated (create keys for BigThings that did not exist in previous batches, and refer to them afterwards), but does not look like a BigDeal to me.

Comment: BTW. Strictly speaking you don't *need* to store the BigThing in a separate table, just storing them in the same table and building a (unique?) constraint/index on them fulfills the same purpose. (except when you rarely use them: then they would make the table wider than necessary)